# What is the equivalent python script of Linux command "strings"?

Tags: python

I am reading some file with a binary content:

adb shell cat /data/somefile.dat

On Linux, after pulling the file from the android device, I can do:

$ strings somefile.dat

to read the file content.

Now I am trying to do the same thing on Windows using Python script.

Any help?

Comment: `strings` is actually a lot more complicated than just finding runs of printable characters -- it recognizes and parses executable file formats as well (which is the logic where it had security bugs come up recently).

Comment: Rather than trying to reimplement this yourself, you might want to get a tool already built for it.  See http://superuser.com/questions/124081/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-strings-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use re to print everything that looks like a string

```
print re.findall("[a-zA-Z0-9]+",open("some_file.data","rb").read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that works for Python3:

```
print(re.findall("[a-zA-Z0-9]+", open(filename, "rb").read().decode('ISO-8859-1')))
```